# Is there is any different between grep stdin and bc stdin?

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, tornado, stdin

There is some code like `os.dup2` in tornado. It will redirect `raw_input()` content into a subprocess.

```
import os,sys
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.process import Subprocess as sp

@coroutine
def run(cmd):
    ioloop = IOLoop().current()
    proc = sp(cmd,shell=True,stdin=sp.STREAM, stdout=sp.STREAM, stderr=sp.STREAM)
    while 1:
        proc.stdin.write(raw_input('input: ')+'\n')
        print 'return: ', (yield proc.stdout.read_bytes(1024,partial=True)).strip()



IOLoop().current().run_sync(lambda :run(sys.argv[1]))
```

If we run bc command like `python test.py bc`, it will appear as follows:

```
# python sa.py bc
input: 1+1
return:  2
input:
```

But if I run with `python test.py 'grep abc'`, will never return anything and hangs up.

```
input: abcdefg
return:  
(hanging up)
```

I guess that is there some difference between `bc`'s stdin and `grep`'s stdin. Can anybody tell me why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `bc` looks for newline to stop reading from stdin (reads a single line), `grep` reads until EOF

Comment: @avigil Not true with my version of `bc`. Try running `bc /dev/stdin` and you can enter in multiple calculations. It only stops at EOF as well.

Comment: `bc` will read multiple lines, it just stops after each line and does something. `grep` doesn't do anything until EOF. Your program never sends an EOF so `grep` never does anything.

Comment: True :) I was misunderstanding your first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between standard input of the two commands. The difference is that `bc` reads one line of input and immediately prints the result. `grep` output is buffered by default so you won't immediately see output.

You can try passing the `--line-buffered` option to grep which will output each line immediately.

You should also keep in mind that `grep` may not produce a line of output for every line of output. This means that if you read in a line which is filtered out by `grep`, your program will hang trying to read the output (since there isn't any).

Comment: thanks a lot. it works now :). but another question, i tried  command `grep -o 'abc' /dev/stdin`,  it can return the match string when i confirm strings with a newline. seems not buffered?

Comment: When stdout is a tty, then grep will default to line buffered mode. This happens when you're running the command directly in your terminal.